# What will happen if every request has a retrofit instance?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I was thinking about a question recently.

**If every request has a retrofit instance,What will happen?**

The reason I want every request has a retrofit instance:

Every **retrofit instance** has an **OkHttpClient instance**,so I want add 
**Interception** to OkhttpClient,but **not every request** should be 
**intercepted**,and I also want to add **some same headers** to OkHttpClient,but **not every request** must has these **same headers**,like when it's login request,I **don't need** add token.,but other request may need.

So my way is to **let every request has a retrofit instance**,I have a demo before,but the quantity of requests are **few**,So I am not sure whether when there are **too many requests** will it **come trouble**?

**I have 2 questions:**

**1.** Will it make some exceptions?Or Will it make stack overflow?

**2.** If there is some better way to solve the question?

**Have someone else has the same experience or have some ideas to question?**

Comment: I use a single OkHttpClient instance with interceptor, and then I use SharedPreferences to check for login status in the intercept method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `@Headers` annotation to add static/dynamic header to `Retrofit`. Moreover, you shouldn't create separate `OkHttp` instance as stated in documentation:

> OkHttp performs best when you create a single OkHttpClient instance and reuse it for all of your HTTP calls. This is because each client holds its own connection pool and thread pools. Reusing connections and threads reduces latency and saves memory. Conversely, creating a client for each request wastes resources on idle pools.

If you want different configuration for each `OkHttp` just use `client.newBuilder()` (available from version 3.x):

> You can customize a shared OkHttpClient instance with newBuilder(). This builds a client that shares the same connection pool, thread pools, and configuration. Use the builder methods to configure the derived client for a specific purpose.

If `@Headers` is not suitable for you, just create as many configurations of `OkHttpClient` as you want to create different `Retrofit` services and you will be ok.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/