# Retrofit: Can I re-use OkhttpClient?

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, okhttp

I am developing an android app using external API servers.

Because I use 2 servers, I have 2 retrofit services.

In my "RemoteDataSource" class's constructor, I make the service objects like:

```
public RemoteDataSource() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        myService1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL_1)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
                .create(MyService1.class);

        myService2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL_2)
                .client(okHttpClient) // my question is here!!!
                .build()
                .create(MyService2.class);
    }
```

What I want to know is...

Can I use one "OkHttpClient" on both services?
Is there any network issue?

or Should I make another OkHttpClient object like "okHttpClient2" and assign it to "myService2"?

Comment: Instead of waiting for someone else to answer, just try it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What will happen if every request has a retrofit instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877956/what-will-happen-if-every-request-has-a-retrofit-instance)

Comment: Yes, you can use the same